# Spring security service's get current user returns incorrect user

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-security-rest

When **User A** logs into my application, then logs out, then **User B** logs in, `springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()` returns **User A**'s domain object.

My front end uses an [api end point](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/#_authentication_endpoint) that comes with the spring-security rest plugin to authenticate and get an access token. The access token is then provided with all request to my api.

This bug only affects one end point, as far as I know. Passing the same access_token with request to the problematic end point and a working one results in their respective calls to `getCurrentUser()` returning two different users.

I am not using any class members static or non-static.

I'm using spring-security-rest (1.5.3) and spring-security-core (2.0.0) for authentication in my grails (2.4.4) application.

The application is running remotely on a Tomcat 7 (Java 7) server. The bug does not occur when the application is run locally on my Mac, which I think is a clue to the problem.

Below is my spring security configuration from by Config.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/assets/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll'],
    '/login/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/blank/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/register/**':                   ['permitAll'],
    '/api/v1/signup':                 ['permitAll'],
    '/api/v1/register':               ['permitAll'],
    '/api/v1/approved_emails':        ['permitAll'],
    '/api/v1/request_password_reset': ['permitAll'],
    '/api/v1/reset_password':         ['permitAll'],
    '/oauth/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/':                              ['isAuthenticated()'],
    '/index':                         ['isAuthenticated()'],
    '/index.gsp':                     ['isAuthenticated()'],
    '/**':                            ['isAuthenticated()']
]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = "/pages/index"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl = "/pages/index"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.defaultTargetUrl = "/"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.sch.strategyName = org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl = '/api/v1/login'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',  // Stateless chain
        '/oauth/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',  // Stateless chain
        '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'                                                                          // Traditional chain
]
```

Below are my URL mappings from UrlMappings.groovy

```
class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
    "/api/v1/document"(resources: "documentRest", includes:['show','update']){
        "/history"(resources: "documentHistoryRest", includes: ['index'])
    }

    "/api/v1/response"(resources: "responseRest", includes:['save', 'show', 'update']) {
        "/candidate_answers"(resources: "messagesRest", includes: ['show']) {
            "/source_document"(resources: "postRest", includes: ['index'])
            "/feedback"(resources: "candidateFeedbackRest", includes: ['save'])
        }
    }

    "/api/v1/result"(resources: "resultRest", includes:['index','update', 'save'])

    "/api/v1/user"(resources: "userRest", includes:['index']) {
        "/memo"(resources: "userMemoRest", includes: ['index','save', 'show','update'])
        "/folders"(resources: "userfoldersRest", includes:['index','save', 'show','update','delete']){
            "/items"(resources: "userfolderItemsRest", includes: ['index','show','save','delete'])
        }
    }

    '/api/v1/location_search'(resources: 'locationSearchRest', includes: ['index'])

    "/api/v1/request_password_reset"(resources: "requestPasswordResetRest", includes: ['save'])

    "/api/v1/reset_password"(resources: "resetPasswordRest", includes: ['save'])

    "/api/v1/register"(resources: "registerRest", includes:['save'])

    "/api/v1/approved_emails"(resources: "approvedEmailsRest", includes: ['index'])

    "/api/v1/autocomplete"(resources: "autoCompleteRest", includes:['index'])

    "500"(view:'/error')
}
}
```

Below is the [debug](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/1.5.3/docs/guide/debugging.html) information from:

```
'/api/v1/response'; against '/api/**'
2016-01-29 18:03:28,583 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /api/v1/response at position 1 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityRequestHolderFilter'
2016-01-29 18:03:28,583 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /api/v1/response at position 2 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
2016-01-29 18:03:28,583 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /api/v1/response at position 3 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RestAuthenticationFilter'
2016-01-29 18:03:28,583 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationFilter  - Actual URI is /api/v1/response; endpoint URL is /api/v1/login
2016-01-29 18:03:28,583 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /api/v1/response at position 4 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-01-29 18:03:28,583 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /api/v1/response at position 5 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RestTokenValidationFilter'
2016-01-29 18:03:28,583 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG bearer.BearerTokenReader  - Looking for bearer token in Authorization header, query string or Form-Encoded body parameter
2016-01-29 18:03:28,584 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG bearer.BearerTokenReader  - Found bearer token in Authorization header
2016-01-29 18:03:28,584 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG rest.RestTokenValidationFilter  - Token found: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2016-01-29 18:03:28,584 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG rest.RestTokenValidationFilter  - Trying to authenticate the token
2016-01-29 18:03:28,584 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationProvider  - Trying to validate token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2016-01-29 18:03:28,584 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG rest.JwtService  - Parsed an HMAC signed JWT
2016-01-29 18:03:28,585 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG jwt.JwtTokenStorageService  - Successfully verified JWT
2016-01-29 18:03:28,585 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG jwt.JwtTokenStorageService  - Trying to deserialize the principal object
2016-01-29 18:03:28,587 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG jwt.JwtTokenStorageService  - UserDetails deserialized: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@ff0d1268: Username: userb@email.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_NO_ROLES
2016-01-29 18:03:28,587 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG rest.JwtService  - Parsed an HMAC signed JWT
2016-01-29 18:03:28,588 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationProvider  - Now is Fri Jan 29 18:03:28 UTC 2016 and token expires at Fri Jan 29 19:01:47 UTC 2016
2016-01-29 18:03:28,588 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationProvider  - Expiration: 3498
2016-01-29 18:03:28,588 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationProvider  - Authentication result: grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.AccessToken(accessToken:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, expiration:3498, refreshToken:null, principal:grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@ff0d1268: Username: userb@email.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_NO_ROLES, super:grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.AccessToken@77be21e4: Principal: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@ff0d1268: Username: userb@email.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_NO_ROLES; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_NO_ROLES)
2016-01-29 18:03:28,589 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG rest.RestTokenValidationFilter  - Token authenticated. Storing the authentication result in the security context
2016-01-29 18:03:28,589 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG rest.RestTokenValidationFilter  - Authentication result: grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.AccessToken(accessToken:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, expiration:3498, refreshToken:null, principal:grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@ff0d1268: Username: userb@email.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_NO_ROLES, super:grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.AccessToken@77be21e4: Principal: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@ff0d1268: Username: userb@email.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_NO_ROLES; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_NO_ROLES)
2016-01-29 18:03:28,589 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG rest.RestTokenValidationFilter  - Continuing the filter chain
2016-01-29 18:03:28,589 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /api/v1/response at position 6 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-01-29 18:03:28,589 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /api/v1/response at position 7 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-01-29 18:03:28,590 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/v1/response; Attributes: [isAuthenticated()]
2016-01-29 18:03:28,590 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Previously Authenticated: grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.AccessToken(accessToken:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, expiration:3498, refreshToken:null, principal:grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@ff0d1268: Username: userb@email.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_NO_ROLES, super:grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.AccessToken@77be21e4: Principal: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@ff0d1268: Username: userb@email.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_NO_ROLES; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_NO_ROLES)
2016-01-29 18:03:28,590 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl  - getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_NO_ROLES] one can reach [ROLE_NO_ROLES] in zero or more steps.
2016-01-29 18:03:28,590 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Authorization successful
2016-01-29 18:03:28,590 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2016-01-29 18:03:28,590 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /api/v1/response reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-01-29 18:03:35,334 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Chain processed normally
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What code logs them in?

Comment: My front end uses an api end point that comes with the spring-security rest plugin to authenticate and get an access token. The access token is then provided with all request to my api.

This bug only affects one end point, as far as I know. Passing the same access_token with request to the problematic end point and a working one results in their respective calls to getCurrentUser() returning two different users.

Comment: It may not help, but you should update to version 2.0.0 of the core plugin, RC4 is quite old.

Comment: `getCurrentUser` works by storing the id from the domain class instance that was used to create the `UserDetails` instance that's used as the `principal` in the `Authentication`. It's purely a utility/convenience method which has little to do with Spring Security. It retrieves the User/Person domain class instance so you can access profile information that's not used by Spring Security.

Comment: If you just need the username, granted roles, or other security-related data you should use `springSecurityService.getPrincipal()` since it's cached and doesn't require database access; only use `getCurrentUser` if you need database data that's not cached in the principal/authentication.

Comment: The method assumes that you're using a fairly standard authentication approach which uses a `UserDetails` (a Spring Security interface) instance as the principal. If that's the case it calls `User.get(id)` and it uses a GORM query by username (which will always be available) if the id (and the more efficient `get()` call) isn't available.

Comment: To add on what Burt said, you would have to enable debug logging as specified in  http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/1.5.3/docs/guide/debugging.html and paste the output

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @BurtBeckwith. I went ahead and updated the plugin to 2.0.0. @ Álvaro Sánchez-Mariscal I edited my post to include the debug information. As you can see, when the /api/v1/response endpoint is hit the plugin correctly authenticates userb@email.com, but getPrincipal() still returns usera@email.com.

Comment: @ÁlvaroSánchez-Mariscal

Answer (score 1):

My hunch was that Spring Security was using a cached SecurityContext from the HttpSession.

So I removed HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter, which stores the SecurityContext in the HttpSession between web requests, from the filter chain in my Config.groovy file and it resolved the problem.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter, -httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter',  // Stateless chain
        '/oauth/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',  // Stateless chain
        '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'                                                                          // Traditional chain
]
```